# My Android Emulator is deadly slow without VT

Tags: android

I have windows 8.1 64bit installed, my Intel CPU did not support VT, so kindly help me to know if there is any way to make my android emulator fast. It is deadly slow, even it looks it is not working, is there any way to make it fast without Intel VT support? i hope i will get the answer. I have tried to install new and old ADT-Bundle.

Comment: VT is there specifically to help with virtualization. "my Yugo car is slow. how can I make it act like a Ferrari". you can't. that's all there is to it.

Comment: you could try the genymotion emulator, though. It may or may not be faster

Comment: njzk2 You would also need VT to use Geny Motion

Comment: simple - You can't unless you have a better CPU which supports VT. Better to think in that direction

Comment: but before this on windows 7 32bit there was no problem with android emulator speed, that was smooth, there for i mention windows 8.1 64bit there!